# What is the appropriate webpack loader for the 'canvas' package in a Next.js?

Tags: canvas, next.js, next.js13, react-konva, konva

I'm currently using [konva](https://www.npmjs.com/package/konva) (& [react-konva](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-konva)) package, to utilize it in Node.js enviroment I also need [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) package installed in. However, when running the code I'm encountering this error:

```
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Could someone please provide guidance on the appropriate loader to use in this case?